# Database in c programming

Tags: c, file-io

.
Hallo everyone,
i'm new in here and also new in c (3 months).

I tryed to make a db in C and the program works fine but i have an issue when i remove the db file (database.txt), i get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct{
    int born;
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    double phoneNumber;
    int record;
}dataBase;

void showRecord(void);
void noRecord(char record[]);
void searchString(FILE *file, char string[]);

int main(void){
    char name[20];
    const char *db = "database.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(db, "r");
    dataBase.record=1;

    printf("Please type First or Last name to search:\t");
    scanf("%s", name);

    searchString(file, name);
    fclose(file);
   return 0;
}

void showRecord(void){
    printf("\n\t\tRecord\t%d\n",dataBase.record++);
    printf("First Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.firstName);
    printf("Last Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.lastName);
    printf("Born:\t\t%d\n", dataBase.born);
    printf("Phone Number:\t%.0f\n", dataBase.phoneNumber);
    printf("------------------------------\n");
}

void noRecord(char record[]){
    printf(KRED "\n\t\t\tNo record found with name\t"RESET KYEL "%s\n"RESET , record);
}

void searchString(FILE *file, char string[]){
    int check = 0;

    while(!feof(file)){
      fscanf(file,"\n%s\t%s\t%d\t%lf\t",dataBase.firstName,dataBase.lastName,&dataBase.born,&dataBase.phoneNumber);

        if(strcasecmp(dataBase.firstName,string)==0){
             showRecord();
             check = TRUE;
        }else if(strcasecmp(dataBase.lastName,string)==0){
             showRecord();
             check = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if(check == FALSE) {
        noRecord(string);
    }
}
```

The db file(database.txt) is:

john    doe    1880    1234567

> mike    michael        1850    7654321
>
> george    hartman    1971    2345678
>
> david    russo        1982    8765432
>
> michael    jackson    1960    3456789

.
When i run it looks like this:
1

```
Please type First or Last name to search:   michael

        Record  1
First Name: mike
Last Name:  michael
Born:       1850
Phone Number:   7654321
------------------------------

        Record  2
First Name: michael
Last Name:  jackson
Born:       1960
Phone Number:   3456789
------------------------------
```

2

```
Please type First or Last name to search:   jack

            No record found with name   jack
```

But if i delete the file, i get:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

In my opinion i think that i have to make a check to see if the file exist, if the file not exist to print the error.
Something like this:

```
if(file == NULL){
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOOPS, Fisierul nu exista\n\n");
    break;
}else{
while(!feof(file)){
  fscanf(file,"\n%s\t%s\t%d\t%lf\t",dataBase.firstName,dataBase.lastName,&dataBase.born,&dataBase.phoneNumber);

    if(strcasecmp(dataBase.firstName,string)==0){
         showRecord();
         check = TRUE;
    }else if(strcasecmp(dataBase.lastName,string)==0){
         showRecord();
         check = TRUE;
    }
}
```

But i don't know how.
Thank You all

Comment: Check for the success of `fopen()`. If it is success, thenonly use the returned file pointer, otherwise stop.

Comment: You are deleting the file in execution time or after deleting you are executing the program??

Comment: i removed myself the file to see whats happends.

i tryed this:

`if((checkFile=fopen(file,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tOOPS, the file doesn't exists\n\n");
    }else{`

but no rezult

Comment: How could that still give a segmentation fault, if the program does nothing?

Comment: have you runed the program ?

Comment: Why using `feof()` is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: ok i change it to:

`while(!feof(file) && !ferror(file))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fopen fails, exit the program.
fscanf will return the number of successfully scanned items. Continue reading the file as long a four items are read.
In the scanf format %19s will prevent overwriting the buffers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct{
    int born;
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    double phoneNumber;
    int record;
}dataBase;

void showRecord(){
    printf("\n\t\tRecord\t%d\n",dataBase.record++);
    printf("First Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.firstName);
    printf("Last Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.lastName);
    printf("Born:\t\t%d\n", dataBase.born);
    printf("Phone Number:\t%.0f\n", dataBase.phoneNumber);
    printf("------------------------------\n");
}

void noRecord(char record[]){
    printf(KRED "\n\t\t\tNo record found with name\t"RESET KYEL "%s\n"RESET , record);
}

void searchString(FILE *file, char string[]){
    int check = 0;

    while( ( fscanf(file," %19s %19s %d %lf",dataBase.firstName,dataBase.lastName,&dataBase.born,&dataBase.phoneNumber)) == 4) {
        //read from file as long as fscanf return four successfully scanned items
        if(strcasecmp(dataBase.firstName,string)==0){
             showRecord();
             check = TRUE;
        }else if(strcasecmp(dataBase.lastName,string)==0){
             showRecord();
             check = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if(check == FALSE) {
        noRecord(string);
    }
}

int main(){
    char name[20];
    char *db = "database.txt";
    FILE *file;
    if ( ( file = fopen(db, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "%s does not exist\nCreate it and try again\n", db);
        return 1; //exit the program
    }
    dataBase.record=1;

    printf("Please type First or Last name to search:\t");
    scanf("%19s", name);

    searchString(file, name);
    fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, with your help the program works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if file exists:

```
int main(){
    char name[20];
    char *db = "database.txt";

    if ((FILE *file = fopen(db, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error\n");
    }

    dataBase.record=1;

    printf("Please type First or Last name to search:\t");
    scanf("%s", name);

    searchString(file, name);
    fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

And i would also advise you to have a look at this (like mention in the comments of your question): [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

EDIT:

I did some improvements to your code, but I did NOT test it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define KRED  "\x1B[31m"
#define KYEL  "\x1B[33m"
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct
{
  int born;
  char firstName[20];
  char lastName[20];
  double phoneNumber;
  int record;
} dataBase;

void showRecord()
{
  printf("\n\t\tRecord\t%d\n",dataBase.record++);
  printf("First Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.firstName);
  printf("Last Name:\t%s\n", dataBase.lastName);
  printf("Born:\t\t%d\n", dataBase.born);
  printf("Phone Number:\t%.0f\n", dataBase.phoneNumber);
  printf("------------------------------\n");
}

void noRecord(char record[])
{
    printf(KRED "\n\t\t\tNo record found with name\t"RESET KYEL "%s\n"RESET , record);
}

void searchString(FILE *file, char *filename){
  int check = 0;

  // You need the filename to newly open the file!
  if ((FILE *checkFile = fopen(filename,"r")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("\n\n\t\t\tOOPS, the File doesn't exist\n\n");

    // Close the file, we don't need it any more.
    fclose (checkFile);

    // EXIT the programm on error
    exit (1);
  }
  else
  {
    // close the file, we don't need it any more.
    fclose (checkFile);
    // You still need to get rid of while(!feof(file))
    while (!feof(file) && !ferror(file)) 
    {
      fscanf(file,"\n%s\t%s\t%d\t%lf\t",dataBase.firstName,dataBase.lastName,&dataBase.born,&dataBase.phoneNumber);

      if (strcasecmp(dataBase.firstName,string)==0)
      {
        showRecord();
        check = TRUE;
      }
      else if (strcasecmp(dataBase.lastName,string)==0)
      {
        showRecord();
        check = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }

  if(check == FALSE)
  {
    noRecord(string);
  }
}

int main(){
    char name[20];
    char *db = "database.txt";

    // Check if file exists on first open!
    if ((FILE *file = fopen(db, "r")) == NULL)
    {
      printf("Error: File doesn't exist'");
      exit(1);
    }

    dataBase.record=1;

    printf("Please type First or Last name to search:\t");
    scanf("%s", name);

    searchString(file, name);
    fclose(file);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind updateing the code in your question, I really can't read code posted in comments.

Comment: in the last post i puted a link with the whole program. ==>>> 

[CLICK HERE](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=8YSxqUNC)

Comment: As this question should help other users in the future too, it would be useful to update the question (use the "edit" link below the question). Your pastebin could be removed by the time someone else is reading this in the future.

Comment: why i can not post an code when i do a replay..says all the time that the message is too long?

Comment: You have to [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29429642/edit) your original question! This should work.